# Numeric instability

Tags: algorithm, numerical-stability

I'm doing some *Linear programming* exercises for the course of Algorithms, and in doing this I'm solving manually many operations with fractions. In doing this I realized that a human being don't suffer from numeric instability: we just keep values in fractional representation, and we finally evaluate (possibly by using a calculator) the value of expressions.

Is there any technique that does this automatically?

Im thinking of something which achieves some kind of symbolic computation, simplifies the numbers internally and finally yields the value only during the evaluation of an expression.

Comment: There are lots and lots of rational fraction libraries.  What language would you like to know about?

Comment: Actually I'm more interested in knowing if this kind of techniques has a specific name. If the library is implemented in some language, it's pretty likely that there's an implementation for any other.

Comment: "I'm more interested in knowing if this kind of techniques has a specific name." "Is there any library (any language will do) that does this automatically?"  Please **update** your question to be complete and consistent.

Comment: @S.Lott, good point, I hope that the edit better gives the idea... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost contains a rational number library [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/rational/index.html) which might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can have a look at [fractions](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html):

```
import fractions
a = fractions.Fraction(2,3)

a*2
# Fraction(4, 3)

a**2
# Fraction(4, 9)

'Value: %.2f' % a
# 'Value: 0.67'
```